# In ASP MVC is there a way access a session state from a shared view such as _Layout.cshml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make it so the links that display on the nav bar from the _Layout view change depedning on whether you are logged in. This is using a SessionStateRepository which I use by initializing it in my controllers.

On the layout page I want to be able to check if 
`state.GetLoginState().email = "anon"`

This is so I can change if the login button is there or not. I just can't find a way to use it on a shared view which goes on all pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, using session state with MVC is a topic of religious debate (for number of good reasons ) and you should definitely read up on that.

But to answer your question, with traditional session class, you can do this

```
@if (HttpContext.Current.Session["email"] == "anon")
{
    <span>Value1</span>
}
else
{
    <span>Value2</span>
}
```

you will have to devise specific implementation on the similar lines based on your repository